# PHP Autologin on multiple devices

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I created some autologin system and i have a problem with login from multiple devices.

When a user logs in, two cookies are sent to the user. First cookie contains user ID, second cookie contains some hashed value which is also saved in database. So, when a user comes back, script takes user id from a cookie, then finds the hashed value in database and compares it with hashed value of the cookie. If the two values match, he's logged in so he can browse the website.

So, the problem with my code is: If user logs in on some other device, new hash will be stored in database, so he will be loged out on the first device.

I can create different table just for autologin system, and i could save different hashed values for different user's browsers ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), but then again, i have a problem. If a user logs in from, let's say, google chrome on two different PCs, again he will be loged out from the first PC with google chrome.

I also have some cookie regenerate method to prevent fixation problem, so when the cookie is regenerated, again, he will be loged out from other devices because hash value in database changed.

I could save more hashed values in database, but if user wants to logout, i wouldn't know from which device to log him out.

So, the main question is, how can i get more information about user's device?

Comment: uh, what about generating every different hashes for different device logins? and bound those hashes into the user account?

Comment: `i wouldn't know from which device to log him out.` But you must know which device the user is currently logged into, for them to login you had to compare the hash to the one(s) in the database..

Comment: Assign each device a fingerprint, could be a random uuid store that on server and in browsers it wont change, include the uuid, user id in your second cookie, and encode and sign it like a JWT, decode/validate, check device id matches user and obviously the id. Do away with the random hash idea, and use SSL or none of it is secure.

Comment: Just use their IP address the code is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. As for the multiple hashes just use another table that stores: ip_add, hash ... Hopefully that's what you meant.